# Print which class edited property

Tags: swift

I need a solution to print a property updated by which file or class.

For example:

I have a struct People.

```
struct People {
  var name: String = ""
}
```

When I edit name in ClassA.swift

```
var people = People()
people.name = "Tom"
```

It will print some log like "ClassA edited People".

Comment: Research willSet and didSet property observers, [this is a good place to start](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID262)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson willSet and didSet will print ClassB

Comment: Ok, maybe I have misunderstood then but that is not a surprise considering how unclear the question is.

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra variable in your structure for checking who has edited **people**. And before changing the variable just update this extra variable.

```
struct People {
  var name: String = ""
  var upDatedBY: String = ""
}
```

and the update property like this -

```
var people = People()
people.upDatedBY = "ClassA"
people.name = "Tom"
```

Then you can observe using **didset**.